# Canada PGWP - Immigrate my spouse to Canada, What are my options?

Tags: canada, express-entry

**BACKGROUND:**

I have a [Post Graduate work permit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/work-postgrad.asp) valid up to 2018. I have a [NOC class A 2175](http://www5.hrsdc.gc.ca/NOC/English/NOC/2011/QuickSearch.aspx?val65=2175) job and I am planning to apply for permanent residence. My employer has already filed a pre-screen application under the International Student with a job offer category under [OINP](http://www.ontarioimmigration.ca/en/pnp/OI_PNPSTUDENTS_JOB.html) in January. The processing time for this application is 90 days. After the approval of this, I have to apply for a Nominee application, the processing time for which is 90 days again which will give me 600 points in my **Express Entry** profile.

I got married in January. My wife is in India and I want to get her in Canada as soon as possible.

Basically I can think of couple of options:

(1) File my Nominee application as married and wait to get the permanent residence under Express Entry which will take me at least 8 months.

(2) Apply for a work permit for my wife as my dependent. Somebody suggested that this process is quick and generally takes only a month. However I could not find a proper link on CIC to do so.

What is the procedure for this?

What are the requirements?

Do I have to show any balance in my bank account?

Does she need to give IELTS or similar exam before coming here?

A link explaining all of this would be really great.

(3) Any other option that I am not aware of.

**UPDATE 1** I have tried calling CIC inquiring this and I have asked a couple questions regarding this. When asked they sent me a generic email dumping all the information in it but not giving answers to my specific questions, so my question still remains the same.

**UPDATE 2** I have tried talking to CIC customer service again today to apply for a spousal work permit making my wife as my dependent. Upon talking to them, I told them I had opened up a MyCIC account under my wife's name and that the application showed that I had to upload the [IMM1295](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/pdf/kits/forms/IMM1295E.PDF) but it isn't asking for any information regarding my job which isn't right because the work permit is dependent on the type of job I have. Upon asking CIC customer service representative about the details about where do I need to provide the information about my job and other info, I was told you have to submit it as optional documents with the application which doesn't seem right as these are the most important documents required for this application. I am really hoping I get some help here because other sources are not being helpful right now.

Comment: The fact that the documents are optional doesn't necessarily imply that they are seen as unimportant to *your* application; it could just mean that such documents are not required for *all* application types.  Is the application form you're using specific to a dependant work permit?  It apppears not to be.  Why would people on the internet be able to give better advice than CIC customer service?

Comment: @phoog That's what I thought too. But I thought people with similar experiences might know what I am doing wrong here. They mention it [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?q=199&t=17) that I should have a job  listed in **Skill Level 0, A or B**. I am pretty sure they would be interested in seeing documents related to my job and more. There is a question checklist which I have to answer and based on that the type of work permit to be applied is decided. So basically I have just answered the questions they asked. I am not sure if it is the right application form or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will leave an answer if this helps future visitors. I applied the work permit through a consultancy firm which asked me this as the document checklist. I got the work permit finally after the processing time ( 2 months)

**Documentary Evidence to be supplied by Student/Worker In Canada on Temporary Residence Visa (Work Permit or Study Permit):**

- Proof of status In Canada : Copy of  Valid Work Permit/Study Permit.
- Copy of Valid Passport ( All Stamp Pages).
- Proof of income i.e. Letter from current employer.
- Last 6 months of Payslips and  6 months Checking Account Bank
  Statement to verify the salary deposited.
- Most Recent   T-1 General (Income Tax Return) & Notice of Assessment
  from Revenue Canada.
- Most Recent  T-4 Statement of Remuneration.
- Proof  Of Funds In Canadian Bank Account. (Recommended Funds $
  12000.00 in Saving Accounts).
- Copy of your Final Transcript & Diploma From College/University.

**Forms to be completed by  Main Applicant outside Canada:**

- Application for Temporary Resident Visa [IMM 5257]
- Family Information [IMM 5645]
- Schedule 1 – Application for Temporary Resident Visa [IMM 5257 –
  Schedule 1]
- Statutory Declaration of Common-law Union [IMM 5409] ( If Applicable)
- IMM 5476-Use of Representative form.

**Documentary Evidence to be Supplied by Main Applicant outside Canada:**

- $255.00 Visa Processing Fee (Online Payment Required Credit Card
  Details).
- Copy of Birth Certificate.
- One passport size Digital Scan photograph.
- Copy of passport (All stamped page).
- Copy of Marriage Certificate.
- Copy of Divorce Certificate (if applicable).
- Employment Confirmation Letter from Current Employer.
- Holiday/Leave Letter from current Employer.
- Last 6 months of Payslips and 6 months Checking Account Bank
  Statement to verify the salary deposited
- Most Recent Year Income Tax Return - Main Applicant.
- All Bank Passbook with recent entries in your Home Country.
- All the Fixed Deposit Copies in your Home Country.
- Current Dated Valuation Reports of Property in your Home country.
- Most Recent  Year Income Tax Return - (Parents or In-laws, If
  applicable to  Support source of income and funds).
- Immigration E-Medical Examination.(Original Confirmation) 
  (http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-perm.asp).
- Police Clearance Certificate for each country you have lived in for
  more than six months since the age of 18.
  (http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/security/police-cert/index.asp)

Not all of these things are required ofcourse, but this a generic checklist they asked for.